# I stole card game c++ header code and it won't compile... duuhhh

Tags: c++, header-files, blackjack

I am a newbie c++ (but fair experience visual basic, visual foxpro)  and I'm trying to get to write a blackjack console program.  I borrowed (stole, used, etc.) header file snippet from an old thread ([Generating a Deck of Cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234388/generating-a-deck-of-cards)).

This is the code:

```
class Card
 {
 public:
 enum ESuit
{
    Hearts,
    Clubs,
    Diamonds,
    Spades,
    Suit_Count
};

enum ERank
{
    Ace,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Jack,
    Queen,
    King,
    Rank_Count
};

static int const skNumCards = Suit_Count * Rank_Count;

Card( int cardIndex )
: mSuit( static_cast<ESuit>( cardIndex / Rank_Count ) )
, mRank( static_cast<ERank>( cardIndex % Rank_Count ) )
{}

ESuit GetSuit() const { return mSuit }; // should be mSuit; }
ERank GetRank() const { return mRank }; // should be mRank; }

private:
    ESuit mSuit;
    ERank mRank;
}  // missing ending ;  should be };
```

It does not compile correctly.  Something is wrong with the lines:

```
ESuit GetSuit() const { return mSuit };  // should be mSuit; }
ERank GetRank() const { return mRank };  // should be mRank; }

private:
    ESuit mSuit;
    ERank mRank;
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Please provide details of the compile error, marking the appropriate lines in the code, if possible.

Comment: You already fixed the `) => }` issue. The semicolon issue is right beside it.

Comment: I didn't include the compile errors because they were so numerous and the first couple led me to realize that the header file had errors.  After stepping back and looking at it fresh I found the semicolons on the wrong side of the 2 lines Esuit GetSuit() and ERank GetRank().  Also no closing semicolon at very end of header file.  Corrected those and I could compile.  Problem with learning a new language is getting required syntax and punctuation marking correct.  Your comments here and in answer are spot on!  Thanks.

Comment: Really wish you provided all of the code.. Dx. Since you stole it I'd like to steal it too x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those lines should be

```
ESuit GetSuit() const { return mSuit; }
ERank GetRank() const { return mRank;}
```

You also need a semi-colon after the closing brace of your class definition.

Comment: You are dead on correct.  Thank you so very much.  I am now on to phase 2 ;)

Comment: "Phase 2" is stealing (borrowing, etc.) the source code of Windows' FreeCell?

Comment: @Jongware My use of the term "stole" was tongue in cheek plus I wanted to generate some attention.  The code provided in this forum is not copyrighted and is understood to be freely available.  Some 3 ****oles decided to vote me down.  Thats a fine "welcome" to someone who has spent hours and hours reading posts in order to learn and then decided to ask a question of his own.  Grow up.